# How to assign leads to a campaign through automation

Tags: apex, soql, community, campaign

Hi friends I'm new to campaigns.I got a requirement like whenever any lead is created with specific field value in a custom field.I have to update in a particular campaign.

Requirement is

I have custom field called CMPId in lead object.

Any lead is created or edited with field value like

CMPID = CM2016

I have already campaign in my org called CMAZ20

I need to update above lead to the campaign.Is there any possibility to automate this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes it is possible.

You need to create a trigger on that'll insert that Lead as a `CampaignMember` object to that campaign. There are a number of ways to do that:

- Click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm) to learn how to use trigger.
- You can also use the Process Builder: [image: Here's a screen shot of the Create Record action]. You just need to pass the Campaign Id.

Comment: Sorry to say i know that through coding it will be done.Is there any possibility to complete with Process builder or flows.And please don't share links like build a basic apex trigger or custom object.It's not related to my question It doesn't help for me because i know basic coding in sfdc. @Fernando Gavinho

Comment: @Pavantej can give your first try and if any issue found then post that

Comment: I had already tried in process builder but i didn't get campaign look up field.It's showing campaign members.So, I am searching for the ways to complete through flows or process builder.I am working on it i will let you know once i got a resolution. @Santanu Boral

Comment: Sorry @Pavantej you weren't specific on your question. You just asked if it was possible to automate. I added the Process Builder to my answer

Comment: Hey sorry i didn't specify excatly because most of the time automation calls for process builder & flows. Thanks buddy you save my time